# Updating fragment TextView from adapter class

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am using a fragment to show a recyclerview with items.

And I have a Adapter class for the recyclerview.

Every time the user clicks on a recyclerview item, I need to change the text from a fragment TextView.

This is the onClick method in adapter class:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            //showPopupMenu(v, position);


            String positi = marcaList.get(position).getnombre();
            Integer positid = marcaList.get(position).getId();

            Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "RESPONSE 2 valor=" + position);

            Toast.makeText(mCtx,"Seleccionados dispositivos de la marca "+positi, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            SharedPreferences prefs3 =
                    mCtx.getSharedPreferences(MISDATOS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);



            SharedPreferences.Editor editor3 = prefs3.edit();
            editor3.putString("nombreMarcaNuevoDisp",positi);
            editor3.putInt("idMarcaNuevoDisp",positid);
            editor3.apply();





        }
```

What I need is to update the text from a TextView in the fragment with the values from the selected list item.

EDIT

Adapter Class:

```
public class MarcasAdapterNuevoDisp extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MarcasAdapterNuevoDisp.ProductViewHolder>  {

    public static String MISDATOS= "MisDatos";
    private Context mCtx;
    private List<Marca> marcaList;
    private SharedPreferences mPref;

    public FragmentManager f_manager;

    public MarcasAdapterNuevoDisp(Context mCtx, List<Marca> marcaList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.marcaList = marcaList;

    }



    public interface OnDataChangeListener{
        public void onDataChanged(int size);
    }


    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.marcas_list, null);
        return new ProductViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {


        Marca marca = marcaList.get(position);
String url = "https://jogua.es/administrar/application/admin/iconos/";
        //loading the image
        Glide.with(mCtx)
                .load(url+marca.geticono())
                .into(holder.imageView);





    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return marcaList.size();
    }

    class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView textViewTitle;
        ImageView imageView;


        public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            //showPopupMenu(v, position);


            String positi = marcaList.get(position).getnombre();
            Integer positid = marcaList.get(position).getId();

            Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "RESPONSE 2 valor=" + position);

            Toast.makeText(mCtx,"Seleccionados dispositivos de la marca "+positi, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            SharedPreferences prefs3 =
                    mCtx.getSharedPreferences(MISDATOS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);



            SharedPreferences.Editor editor3 = prefs3.edit();
            editor3.putString("nombreMarcaNuevoDisp",positi);
            editor3.putInt("idMarcaNuevoDisp",positid);
            editor3.apply();





        }




    }
}
```

Comment: Just pass MainActivity.this as parameter in your Adapter and make TextView as public.

Comment: @Shane, what do you mean with passing MainActivity.this as parameter in the adapter? The TextView is already public in the fragment.

Comment: You don't need `SharedPreferences` for this simple use case.. You can directly call a public method which inside fragment and do process from adapter class.

Comment: You can pass fragment object to your adapter and access the textview in your adapter class, or else post your whole adapter class, or constructor..

Comment: @Gunaseelan, I am using SharedPreferences for another purpose here.

Comment: @Gunaseelan, I have included the adapter class in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use following way,

Add field for fragment and change your adapter constructor like this,

```
private MarcasFragment fragment;
public MarcasAdapterNuevoDisp(MarcasFragment fragment, List<Marca> marcaList) {
    this.mCtx = fragment.getActivity();
    this.fragment = fragment;
    this.marcaList = marcaList;

}
```

Then in your onclick method,

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    fragment.textView.setText(yourString); //As your textview is public, you can access it from here.
}
```

Comment: Changing the adapter constructor makes an exception at fragment adapter definition: adapter = new MarcasAdapterNuevoDisp(getActivity(), marcaList);

Comment: instead of `getActivity()` pass `this`

Answer (score 1):

you can create an Interface and use the interface to setText in your textview like this:-

Interface :-

```
 public interface IOnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(String text);
    }
```

use Interface in fragment and pass this iOnItemClickListener in your adapter constructor:-

```
private IOnItemClickListener iOnItemClickListener = new IOnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(String text) {

          yourTextView.setText(text);

        }
    };
```

and in your adapter create an object in your adapter :-

```
private IOnItemClickListener iClickListener; 

public SearchAdapter(Context ctx, IOnItemClickListener iClickListener, ArrayList<SearchResponse> arrayList) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        **this.iClickListener = iClickListener;**
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }
```

and when your click on item;-

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                iClickListener.onItemClick("pass your text");
            }
        });
```

Comment: leave a comment if you have any query

Comment: I don´t understand where should go your second piece of code

Comment: I have implemented all your code but don´t know what to do with this: private IOnItemClickListener iClickListener; 

public SearchAdapter(Context ctx, IOnItemClickListener iClickListener, ArrayList<SearchResponse> arrayList) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        **this.iClickListener = iClickListener;**
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }