# How to Access Fragment's TextView inside an Adapter Class?

Tags: android

> Hi, I am trying to Update a TextView which is in a Fragment from my adapter class. I followed this tutorial, but **no luck** : [Updating fragment TextView from adapter class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56186400/updating-fragment-textview-from-adapter-class)

> I tried to pass HomeFragment in the `BottomSheetAdapter`:

```
  public BottomSheetAdapter(HomeFragment fragment, List<UserDetailsModel> userDetailsModelList, Context context) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
    this.userDetailsModelList = userDetailsModelList;
    this.context = context;
}
```

> This is how I am setting the Text from BottomSheetAdapter: , My TextView is `userLocation`

```
 holder.addressCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
 fragment.userLocation.setText("Hello World");
 }
  }
```

> And in my BottomSheetDialog, this is how I am initialising the BottomSheetAdapter:

```
HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
bottomSheetAdapter = new BottomSheetAdapter(homeFragment, userDetailsModelList, getActivity());
```

> This is the Error I am getting :

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference
```

> How to fix it. Please guide.Thanks in advance

Comment: From where do you open `BottomSheetAdapter`, from `homefragment` or some other class

Comment: It seems your fragment class neither inflated nor attached to Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like fragment object created but text view is not initialized. Please create a method in HomeFragment() to initialize the text view and call the method before passing the fragment object to adapter.

Comment: What do you mean exactly ? I have initialised the TextView at the very top in HomeFragment

Comment: May I know where you initialize the TextView object? Can you please share the code?

Comment: @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        TextView userLocation = view.findViewById(R.id.userLocation);

Comment: Ok. But you just initialized adapter after the object creation of HomeFragment(). That doesn't mean that onCreateView() is completed. Your adapter initialization should be done at the end of onCreateView() of your fragment.